# How to output those data with certian column number (not field value)?

Tags: bash

I am analyzing my research data with various column number shown below.

```
....
FRAM_#         9100         2275(fs)  CN= 0 PRMRYTGT     13598      O    13600      H  0.962     13599      H  0.942
FRAM_#         9200         2300(fs)  CN= 0 PRMRYTGT     13598      O    13600      H  0.983     13599      H  0.977
FRAM_#         9300         2325(fs)  CN= 0 PRMRYTGT     13598      O    13600      H  1.022     13599      H  1.022
FRAM_#         9400         2350(fs)  CN= 0 PRMRYTGT     13598      O    13600      H  0.962     13599      H  0.926
FRAM_#         9500         2375(fs)  CN= 0 PRMRYTGT     13598      O    13600      H  0.985     13599      H  1.030      8279        CA  3.185
FRAM_#         9600         2400(fs)  CN= 0 PRMRYTGT     13598      O    13600      H  0.985     13599      H  0.949      8279        CA  3.149
FRAM_#         9700         2425(fs)  CN= 0 PRMRYTGT     13598      O    13600      H  0.984     13599      H  1.021      8279        CA  3.062
FRAM_#         9800         2450(fs)  CN= 0 PRMRYTGT     13598      O    13600      H  0.999     13599      H  1.017     
FRAM_#         9900         2475(fs)  CN= 0 PRMRYTGT     13598      O    13600      H  1.007     
....
```

The column number for each row may be various. Each column is divided by one or more spaces. I want to ONLY show those data with column number=14, like

```
....
    FRAM_#         9100         2275(fs)  CN= 0 PRMRYTGT     13598      O    13600      H  0.962     13599      H  0.942
    FRAM_#         9200         2300(fs)  CN= 0 PRMRYTGT     13598      O    13600      H  0.983     13599      H  0.977
    FRAM_#         9300         2325(fs)  CN= 0 PRMRYTGT     13598      O    13600      H  1.022     13599      H  1.022
    FRAM_#         9400         2350(fs)  CN= 0 PRMRYTGT     13598      O    13600      H  0.962     13599      H  0.926
    FRAM_#         9800         2450(fs)  CN= 0 PRMRYTGT     13598      O    13600      H  0.999     13599      H  1.017 
....
```

How can I run BASH scripts to list these data?

NOTE: my data has more than million lines. I need to consider the scripts efficiency. Any further help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't awk's `NF` variable provide all the information you need?

Comment: eg. `awk '{ print $14 }' ./dat.txt `

Comment: @jenesaisquoi He wants to print the whole line when there are 14 columns, not just print column 14.

Comment: @Barmar ah I see, I just figured the OP wasn't familiar with `awk`, so they would want something like `awk 'NF == 14 { print }' ./dat.txt `

Comment: @jenesaisquoi if you're going to give the answer, put it in a real answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, I thought you wanted to close it, but I can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `awk` (or better `gawk` if you have it) specializes in tasks such as this where you need to operate on column formatted data.  Using the `NF` variable (awk's builtin variables are all short capitalized pneumonics) you can determine rows with "Number Fields" (`NF`), and print those, eg.

```
awk 'NF == 14 { print }' ./dat.txt
```

Note `awk` is a line oriented language, so this will execute the block `{ print }` on lines where the condition is true (in an `awk` sense of true).  You will need to refer to the manual for details, I'm simply an `awk` user, not a specialist.

Comment: That should work, too: `awk 'NF == 14' ./dat.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ if (NF == 14) { print } }' inp.txt >> ans.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NF == 14'
```

Awk will use the default command of { print $0 } if no command is specified for a given pattern.